# How to pass values between functional components in ReactJS- output [object Object]/undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, undefined, react-functional-component

I'm having trouble passing a prop in functional components that are in the same .js file. I tried posting this problem before but it was no help.

I would like to get `member_id` from the GET request in my first function `GetMemID` and use it to set `member_id` of my useState in my second function `Transactions`.

I know my GET request is working because I am able to see the data after I inspect my code.

With my code so far, I am getting "[object Object]" when I display `member_id` in `Transactions`.

This is my code so far:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import moment from 'moment';
import  HomeNavBar from '../components/HomeNavBar.js';

var currentDate = moment().format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss");

function GetMemID() {

  const [details, setDetails] = useState([]);  
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  fetch("http://########/api/members/get/", options)
  .then(response => {
    if (response.status !== 200) {
      console.log(response.status);
      setError(response);
    }
    response.json().then(data => {
      setDetails(data);
    });
  });
}, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {details.map(item => (
         <Transaction member_id={item.member_id} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

function Transaction({member_id}) {
//props.state
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [trans, setTrans] = useState({member_id:member_id, category:'', description:'', amount:0}); 
  const [details, setDetails] = useState({id:0, mmeber_id:0, group:"", username:""});

  console.log("member_id: " + member_id);


//GET rerquest to get transaction memberID
  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
    },
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://########/api/members/get/", options)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        console.log(response.status);
        setError(response);
      }
      response.json().then(data => {
        setDetails(data);
      });
    });
  }, []);

  //POST request to API for transaction
  const optionPOST = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
    },
    body:JSON.stringify(trans)
  }

  const createTransaction = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    fetch("http://########/api/transactions/post/", optionPOST)
    .then((response) => console.log('reponse: ' + response.json()))
    .then((message) => console.log('message: ' + message))
  }

  if (error) {
    return (<Redirect to="/Signin" />);
  } else{
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <HomeNavBar />
        <form>
          <div className="form-horizantal">
            <fieldset>
              <div className="form-group row">
                <label className="col-md-12"><p>{currentDate}</p></label>
              </div>
              
              <div className="form-group row">
                <label className="col-md-12">
                  <p>Member ID</p>
                  <input type="text" name="member_id" defaultValue={trans.member_id} readOnly/>
                </label>
              </div>
              
              <div className="form-group row">
                <label className="col-md-12">
                  Select Category
                </label>
              </div>

              <div className="form-group row">
                <label className="col-md-12">
                  <select value={trans.category} onChange={e => setTrans({ ...trans, category: e.target.value })} >
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="billsutilities">Bills/Utilities</option>
                    <option value="groceries">Groceries</option>
                    <option value="health">Health</option>
                    <option value="transportation">Transportation</option>
                    <option value="ehoppingentertainment">Shopping/Entertainment</option>
                    <option value="mics.">Mics.</option>
                  </select>
                </label>
              </div>

              <div className="form-group row">
                <label className="col-md-12">
                  <p>Description</p>
                  <input type="text" name="description" value={trans.description} onChange={e => setTrans({ ...trans, description: e.target.value })} />
                </label>
              </div>

              <div className="form-group row">
                <label className="col-md-12">
                  <p>Amount</p>
                  <input type="text" name="amount" value={trans.amount} onChange={e => setTrans({ ...trans, amount: e.target.value })} />
                </label>
              </div>
            </fieldset>

            <button type="submit" onClick={createTransaction}>Submit</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Transaction;
```

Comment: How is the data from the API structured?

Comment: Log the value of `item` just before `<Transaction member_id={item.member_id} />`

Comment: `console.log("member_id: " + member_id);`  the forth line below `function Transaction({member_id}) {` what does it show in console?

Comment: @kayuapi_my, it shows "member_id: undefined"

Comment: @WebbH, it's formatted as JSON.

Comment: @MohammadAbdulAlim, no matter how I try to log the value of item, it does not display anything. Is it because I am not exporting the function?

Comment: Please log `data` before `setDetails(data);`

Answer (score 0):

```
const [isLoading,setIsLoading] = useState(false)
useEffect(() => {
  fetch("http://########/api/members/get/", options)
  .then(response => {
    if (response.status !== 200) {
      console.log(response.status);
      setError(response);
    }
    response.json().then(data => {
      setDetails(data);
      setIsLoading(true);
    });
  });
}, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {isLoading && details.map(item => (
         <Transaction member_id={item.member_id} />
      ))}
    </div>
```

The possible solutions are ->
1 ) As I have used the isLoading state in the above code sample, which is initially false and set true when data is loaded from API. And conditionally render the Transaction component.
2 ) To debug it more clearly, log value of state details (to be sure that we are getting data correctly), something like this ->

```
useEffect(()=>{
console.log(details);
},[details])
```

3. Also check if all keys of JSON data coming from API and typed correctly.

Do share your review if it worked for you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

Storing passed props into local state is anti-pattern in React. The issue you have is that `Transaction` is mounted and rendered ***before*** the GET request in `GetMemID` resolves and updates the `details` state.

## Solution 1

Just consume the passed `member_id` prop directly in the `Transaction` component. `trans.member_id` is used only once and never updated, so there's no point to it being in state.

```
const [trans, setTrans] = useState({ category:'', description:'', amount:0 });

...

<input type="text" name="member_id" defaultValue={member_id} readOnly/>
```

## Solution 2

If you really absolutely ***must*** store `member_id` into state then you need to use an `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the props value to update the state. When the passed `member_id` prop value updates the effect callback will update `trans.member_id`.

```
const [trans, setTrans] = useState({
  member_id,
  category:'',
  description:'',
  amount:0,
});

useEffect(() => {
  setTrans(trans => ({
    ...trans,
    member_id
  }));
}, [member_id]);
```

***Note:** Both solutions assume you are correctly fetching and updating the `details` state in the parent component.*